# Tool to combine multiple javascript files into one...

Tags: javascript

Is there a tool which can combine multiple javascript files into one and then compress them?

Comment: for command-line solution: install `npm install uglify-js -g` globally and then do `uglifyjs file1.js file2.js  -o output.js -c -m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHP, try Minify:  http://code.google.com/p/minify/

From the docs:

> Minify is a PHP5 app that helps you
>   follow several of Yahoo!'s Rules for
>   High Performance Web Sites.
>
> It combines multiple CSS or Javascript
>   files, removes unnecessary whitespace
>   and comments, and serves them with
>   gzip encoding and optimal client-side
>   cache headers.

Answer (score 6):

[Yahoo - YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

[Google - Closure Comipler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) (+ [Online Service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home))

[JSMin - the JavaScript minifier](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html)

[Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/download/#packer)

Combining JSMin and Packer into a command line tool - [SmallSharpTools Packer](http://svn.offwhite.net/trac/SmallSharpTools.Packer/wiki)

Comment: What could work with more than one file?

I need to process directory with the files and then get only one file.

Comment: SmallSharpTools Packer can do this - but you could do this yourself, combine all files into one (using file1.js >> combined.js file2.js >> combined.js for example) before passing to a minifier/packer tool.

Answer (score 2):

For people who want something lightweight and flexible, I created [js.sh](https://github.com/benjaminwy/js.sh) today to address this problem.  It's a simple command line tool targeted toward JS files that could easily be modified to take care of CSS files too.  Benefits:

- Easily configurable for use by multiple developers on a project
- Combines JS files in the order specified in script_order.txt
- Compresses them with Google's Closure Compiler
- Splits JS into <25kb chunks where possible since the iPhone won't cache anything greater than 25kb
- Generates a small PHP file with `<script>` tags that you can include where appropriate
- Usage: `js.sh -u yourname`

It could use some improvements, but it's better for my use case than all of the other solutions I've seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

Join the files, paste here http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ and pack with shrink variables and base64 encode the minified code is evaluable

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool because I have exactly the same problem that you have.
See JSCombiner here: https://bitbucket.org/ardee_aram/jscombiner/

What makes it different is that it watches your javascript files for changes, and combines them when such change occurs. It then relieves you form "building" your javascript everytime you want to view it in your browser. It doesn't have compression though but I see that [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) has a JAR file so I can integrate it when I have the time.

Hope this helps you as well :)