# Phonegap + Jquery app: Scripts taking time to load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm building a phonegap + JQM app. I have a loader.html which is the first file which shows up when the app starts. In this file I'm linking all the js files. This loading of external js file is taking a little longer than desired, around 5-6 seconds. Only then it goes away from the loader file to my home page. Is this the correct way to load the files?
I have the following:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<script src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/childbrowser.js"></script>
<script src="js/swipe.js"></script>
<script src="js/barcodescanner.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" ></script>
<script src="js/dbaccess.js"></script>
<script src="js/FBConnect.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in loading script . you can use two tech. 
`combine` and `minify` to improve performance of your app.

**COMBINE**
this one is used to combine number of external files into one . it will reduce 
number of request to download script files

**MINIFY**
this one perform some optimizations on your JavaScript to remove whitespace, shorten variable names and remove unused code.

refer this link for minification tools  [Tool to combine multiple javascript files into one...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947231/tool-to-combine-javacripts-files-into-one)

Answer (score 0):

Using minified version of JavaScript files, is the better option to solve this issue.

Minification in JavaScript, is the process of removing all unnecessary characters from source code, without changing its functionality. These unnecessary characters usually include white space characters, new line characters, comments, and sometimes block delimiters, which are used to add readability to the code but are not required for it to execute.
We have lot of minification tools online.

[JS Compress](http://jscompress.com/)
[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

[Here](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/11/7-free-tools-to-minify-your-scripts-and.html) is a list of free tools for minification.

Note : Before minifying your script make sure that each line is ended with a semicolon or it may make issues.